# How to maintain state of a label during postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
 How to maintain a value assigned to a label through javascript after postback?
```

**Problem:**          I have assigned a label value using a clientside function.
                           But whenever postback happened, label values are gone.

**Solution i found:** After searching a lot, all are suggessting to store and retrieve
                           the value to & from a hidden field.

**Note:**             But i want to achieve this without using  hidden field as it may
                           increase pageload time.

Comment: Use `<asp:Label />` control and Show how you are assigning value

Comment: What about localStorage, sessionStorage and cookie?

Comment: is this webforms or MVC?

Comment: "But i want to achieve this without using hidden field as it may
increase pageload time." Not really for just one label

Comment: @MortenAnderson its a webform

Comment: @Satpal <asp:Label id="lbl1" clientidmode="static" runat="server"/> $('#lbl1').text('testText').

Comment: @MadhanSekar, That will suffice and add that as an edit to question

Comment: @MadhanSekar purpose of Label is just the presentation of data(some meaningful interpretation of some code data)..on postback, the label text has to be set the same way it was set for the first time..if you are wanting to read the text from html page, its not correct approach..because its not right to make some decision based on the label text.. have an explicit hidden field to store actual code data(say employeeId while your label shows the employee name)

Comment: Please visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657063/how-to-get-control-value-after-javascript-refresh/20718750#20718750), i have answered a question, which may solve your problem too I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The state of `label` is not maintained in `ViewState` by *asp.net*. The labels are converted in to spans and the html of span is not posted on submitting form, this is why changes made by client are not persisted. You can put the state of label in some hidden field when you change it in javascript and access it on server.

**HTML**

```
<input id="hdnLabelState" type="hidden" runat="server" >
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdnLabelState.ClientID %>').value = "changed value of span";
```

*Server side (code behind)*

```
string changedLabelValue = hdnLabelState.Value;
```

Comment: i need an alternative for this hiddenfield. is it possible?

Comment: You can use <asp:hidden field, which is also converted to input, type = "hidden". You can send ajax call to send the updated state but that is not suitable here.

Comment: but my textbox value(s) assigned through jquery also not maintained during postback. How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

use `html hidden field`

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenlabel">
```

Answer (score 0):

try an html label, like

```
<label id="lbl" runat="server">Myv alue</label>
```